# Is angle $EBA$ is a right angle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am having trouble analyzing this image to identify the statement as true or false: 
[image]

The statements are:

1. angle $EBA$ is a right angle. - I think it's false, but I can't think of a theorem or postulate that will justify my answer.
2. $\overleftrightarrow{FG}$ is perpendicular to plane $H$. - I think this is wrong because $\overleftrightarrow{FG}\subseteq{H}$

please help. thank you

Comment: You need to get conclusions from just looking at the picture? Don't you have more info?

Comment: @JulianMejia yes. it's just the figure that's given. that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Are planes K,N perpendicular hinged along ABC  in three dimensions? Where is plane H marked?

Comment: You are right for the second part. But for the first part $EBA$ might be a right angle (actually it looks a right triangle assuming the parallelogram representing $H$ is actually a rectangle from other perspective.

Comment: @Narasimham the plane on the left side.

Comment: @JulianMejia well, it didn't say it's a parallelogram. but it seems to be a right angle. I just can't think of any theorem other than : When a line is perpendicular to two lines on the plane (where they intersect), it is perpendicular to the plane. It will also be perpendicular to all lines on the plane that intersect there.

Comment: Well can you draw a different line $KBJ$ in the same plane $UNREADABLEBLURRYLETTER$ that line $DBE$ is in?  In not, why not?  If you can could you distinguish the difference in the angle $ABE$ and $ABJ$?

Comment: @fleablood I tried that, it doesn't look like a right angle. well, my reason is just it doesn't look like it is. for me, the information is not enough to determine whether that angle is right angle.

Comment: My point was, with just the info given in the picture there's no reason for anything.  The angle can be any angle.  The only requirement seems to be that $AB$ is a line in the plane with a blurry unreadable letter and that it intersects the line $AC$ at one point there are, of course, an infinite number of such lines of varying angles.  If it can possible not be perpendicular than you can't conclude it is.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are two mutually perpendicular planes intersecting along ABC in the 3D figure I have redrawn. It is assumed ABC is perpen to the bigger plane on which the union is mounted.From the picture assuming BE is is parallel to the plane shown and ABC is perpendicular to it..then

it is correct EBA is a right triangle.

FG is perpendicular to plane K, the piercing point is C.

[image]

Comment: Why????  How do you know any of that stuff?  And Why is ABE a right angle?  Why isn't it $100$ degrees or $80$ degrees?

Comment: I was trying to help out OP to get some probable interptetation of image projected from 3d ( parallel and perpendicular lines )